# Accessing Extension Objects

Tags: .net, xslt

I've added an object to the XsltArgumentList. I was wondering how I could access and display it in my transformation?

```
xslarg.AddExtensionObject("someKey", "someValue");
```

However, when I transform, I wan't to be able to display "someValue".

Any idea how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension objects are not intended to be used to pass values into the stylesheet. They are used solely to provide extension *functions* to the stylesheet (hence "*extension* object"). To pass data, use `<xsl:param>` and `XsltArgumentList.AddParam`.